# dhcpd: varying vendor-class-identifier

Tags: dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I'm having trouble selectively sending parameters in response to a DHCP Inform packet using groups (or even without, just using host declarations) for bootp stuff. My configuration file right now looks like:

```
subnet 130.123.131.128 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
  allow unknown-clients;
}
host dev-mac-09 {
  option vendor-class-identifier "example-identifier";
  hardware ethernet 10:9a:dd:51:ff:83;
}
```

If I put `vendor-class-identifier` in the global scope, using tcpdump I can see that the client receives the vendor class option successfully. If I take it out, and just keep it in the host scope (or group scope), the client never receives the option. Specifying `option dhcp-parameter-request list 60` doesn't help either.

I did try using a class definition inside a group, but then it applied even if the host wasn't a part of the group.

As an aside, how do I get detailed logging? At least something to indicate what groups and things got used to generate the response to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure vendor-class-identifier is intended to be used as a configuration item sent by the server.  Usually it is a vendor-defined value sent by the client to tell the server what type of host it is.

Apart from creating a trace file by using the -tf option to dhcpd, there doesn't appear to be any additional logging or debug option.